# Filter Bootstrap Table with start and end date using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, filter, bootstrap-table

I have Bind dynamically bootstrap table using JSON values. This table contain Start Date and End Date column. So i have to filter Bootstrap table between yesterday and today. I am having separate dropdown called date filter if i changed date as "month". It will filter current month data in bootstrap table. So please find below code,

**HTML:**

```
<table id="eventsTable" data-checkbox="true" data-sortable="true" data-row-style="rowStyle"></table>



<div class="pull-left tableAction hide" onchange="filtersByDate()">
                <select class="form-control" id="date">
                    <option value="<any date>">Any date</option>
                    <option value="Today">Today</option>
                    <option value="Current Week">CurrentWeek</option>
               </select>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "apilist",
            data: "",
            success: function (response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            var data = [];
                            $.each(response.Slip, function (index) {
                                var obj = {};
                                obj.SlipID = response.Slip[index].SlipID;
                                obj.Client = response.Slip[index].Client;
                                obj.Start = response.Slip[index].StartDate;
                                obj.End = (response.Slip[index].EndDate;
                                data.push(obj);
                            });
                            $('#eventsTable').bootstrapTable({
                                columns: [
                                    { field: "state", checkbox: true },
                                    { field: "SlipID", title: 'SlipID', sortable: true, class : "hide" },
                                    { field: "Client", title: 'Client', sortable: true },
                                    { field: "Start", title: "Start", sortable: true },
                                    { field: "End", title: "End", sortable: true },
                                ],
                                data: data,
                            });
                        }
              }
});

function filtersByDate()
{
    startDate= $("#startDate").val();
    endDate = $("#startDate").val();
    searchFunction(startDate,endDate);
}
function searchFunction(startDate, endDate) {
var table, tr, td, td2, i;
    table = document.getElementById("eventsTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[13];
        td2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[14];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML != "-") {
                var dateFormat = new Date(parseInt(td.innerHTML.split('-')[0]), parseInt(td.innerHTML.split('-')[1]), parseInt(td.innerHTML.split('-')[2]));
                var startdateFormat = new Date(parseInt(startDate.split('-')[0]), parseInt(startDate.split('-')[1]), parseInt(startDate.split('-')[2]));
                if (dateFormat >= startdateFormat) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
       }
        if (td2) {
            if (td2.innerHTML != "-") {
                var dateFormat = new Date(parseInt(td2.innerHTML.split('-')[0]), parseInt(td2.innerHTML.split('-')[1]), parseInt(td2.innerHTML.split('-')[2]));
                var enddateFormat = new Date(parseInt(endDate.split('-')[0]), parseInt(endDate.split('-')[1]), parseInt(endDate.split('-')[2]));
                if (dateFormat <= enddateFormat) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know your suggestions,

Comment: Since you are already using loop to create object, i guess it would be okay if you use if else there to filter out the data that you don't want to show, unless you don't want to do that.

Comment: I am having separate dropdown called date filter if i changed date as "month". It will filter current month data.

Comment: " It will filter current month data in bootstrap table."...ok, so it sounds like you've already got that working? It's not clear what the problem is or what your question is. Is the problem to filter it the same way when returning from the ajax call?

Comment: Will the data be filtered from server side or client side?

Comment: Actually I have Bootstrap table that are already bind in jquery. So we have come with the filter. If i changed the dropdown value like current month, The bootstrap table display only current month data.

Comment: yes you've already said that. So what's the _problem_? What do you want us to help you with?

Comment: I need script for filtering the date. I have written javascript code as follow,

Comment: ?? You just told us (twice) that you already have something which does the filtering. You said " If i changed the dropdown value like current month, The bootstrap table display only current month data.". That sounds like a description of an existing feature. Are you trying to say that's what you _want_, and not what you've already got? Perhaps we just have a language barrier here. If you write something in the present tense, we assume it already exists. Perhaps you meant to write in the future tense.

Comment: No I Yet not done the filtering. My requirement is have to do the filter between start and end date

Comment: Ok, I see. I think you need to improve your English a little so that you don't write questions or requests as if they are statements of fact. Anyway that's a separate thing. So, next question is, what have you tried to do so far? This is not a free write-my-code service. We are volunteers and will spend our time to help you with your attempt to solve your problem, if we can see you spent some time to research and try it yourself first. To be honest though, there are lots of Javascript table plugins out there already which will do filtering/sorting etc for you - did you search for it?

Comment: Please check updated script. I have tried to filter bootstrap table nut its not working correctly. @ADyson

Comment: Since that's a bit of a wall of code you'll need to be a bit more specific about what goes wrong. Give an example of input data, expected output and current output. But really, like I said, you should strongly consider just using a plugin for this, it'll almost certainly save you a lot of time and difficulty. There are lots of them available, some of which are explicitly compatible with bootstrap.

Comment: Actually, from where did you get this bootstrapTable extension? Is it http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/?  If you read that page it seems to have some methods for filtering already

Comment: @ArunD It looks to me like your code is not doing things the "bootstrap-table" way. Bootstrap-table provides a "filterBy" method which enables you to filter the table rows.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found the solution,

tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[13] is the start date in bootstrap table

tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[14] is the end date in bootstrap table

**JS**

```
 function searchFunction(startDate, endDate) {
        var table, tr, td, td2, i;
        table = document.getElementById("eventsTable");
        var startValue = false;
        var endValue = false;
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[13];
            td2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[14];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML != "-") {
                    if ((new Date(td.innerHTML)).getTime() >= (new Date(startDate)).getTime()) {
                        startValue = true;
                    } else {
                        startValue = false;
                    }
                }
           }
            if (td2) {
                if (td2.innerHTML != "-") {
                    if ((new Date(td2.innerHTML)).getTime() <= (new Date(endDate)).getTime()) {
                        endValue = true;
                    } else {
                        endValue = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (i != 0) {
                if (startValue == true && endValue == true) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                }
                else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks